# How do I create batch folder from part of file name, move files into folder with a modified name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a list of files with the following filename

gml_Object_**obj_A**_Script_0.txt

gml_Object_**obj_B**_Script_1.txt

with **obj_A, obj_B** is the name of objects
and *Script_0, Script_1* is the file names

I need a Windows batch file to create folder based on object name, then move the files to each folder and rename it

In the example above, after using the batch file, I'll have 2 folders

Folder **obj_A**, contains file *Script_0*.txt

Folder **obj_B**, contains file *Script_1*.txt

So far I've come across a nice post here
[How do I create folder from file name and move files into folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326060/how-do-i-create-folder-from-file-name-and-move-files-into-folder)

But I'm not good with Windows Batch command, so I can't modify it to match my need

Here's my code (which is NOT WORKING)

```
    @echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceDir=E:\TestBatch"
set "DestDir=E:\TestBatch"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A-D-H "%SourceDir%\gml_Object_obj_*" 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "eol=| tokens=2 delims=_" %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
        md "%DestDir%\%%B" 2>nul
        set "FileName=%%A"
        call move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%A" "%DestDir%\%%B\%%FileName:~3%%"
    )
)
endlocal
```

The result after running this code, is one folder called "Object" with 2 files

_Object_obj_A_Script_0.txt

_Object_obj_B_Script_1.txt

Comment: I updated the question, my bad for not making it clear in the first place. @Compo

Comment: You want `obj_A`, which is `<token3>_<token4>`, but you extract `<token2>` instead. Besides that, you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysing **your code**,

`%%A` would contain a filename, eg. `gml_Object_obj_A_Script_0.txt`.

`%%B` is set to the second `_`-delimited token of `%%~nA`, which is `Object`. (The `~n` picks the **n**ame part of `%%A`,so is irrelevant here)

The destination directory is established using `%%B`=`Object`

`filename` is set to `%%A`=`gml_Object_obj_A_Script_0.txt`

The `move` command is CALLed. This executes

```
    move /Y "E:\TestBatch\gml_Object_obj_A_Script_0.txt" "E:\TestBatch\Object\%FileName:~3%"
```

Where `filename` is set to `gml_Object_obj_A_Script_0.txt`, so the `move` filename is `gml_Object_obj_A_Script_0.txt` except for the first 3 characters, hence `_Object_obj_A_Script_0.txt`

It would appear that Stephan has missed the `call` keyword.

So - that's why your code acted as it did.

---

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%E in ('dir /B /A-D-H "%SourceDir%\gml_Object_obj_*" 2^>nul') do (
 for /F "eol=| tokens=3,4* delims=_" %%U in ("%%E") do (
  md "%DestDir%\%%U_%%V" 2>nul
  move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%E" "%DestDir%\%%U_%%V\%%W" >nul
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

```
I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) 
ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs 
(See `for/f` from the prompt for documentation)
```

My code: (I'll use YOUR directorynames)

`%%E` would contain a filename, eg. `gml_Object_obj_A_Script_0.txt`.

`%%U` is set to the third `_`-delimited token of `%%A`, which is `obj`,
`%%V` to the fourth, `A` and `%%W` to the remainder, `Script_0.txt`.

The destination directory is established using `%%U_%%V`=`obj_A`

The `move` command is executed

```
    move /Y "E:\TestBatch\gml_Object_obj_A_Script_0.txt" "E:\TestBatch\obj_A\Script_0.txt"
```

Comment: My God! It works like a charm! Thanks for your brilliant answer. 

I'd like to know more, if you don't mind.

In which command do we assign the value for %%V and %%W? 

Because I can't see %%V and %%W defined anywhere before that (sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm just curious about the code"

Comment: The token numbers listed in the `tokens=` option are assigned, lowest to the nominanated metavariable (`%%U`), next-lowest to the next alphabetically and so on. Token `*` means the remainder of the string after the highest token number allocated. The documentation is cleverly hidden but executing `for /?` from the prompt will reveal all.....